# LAB conversion using C++

Tags: c++, operators

I'm using this function that convert RGB colors of an image to the LAB space. I don't understand the lines 13, 14 and 15 since they use particular symbols (>>) and hexadecimal numbers:

```
void RGB2LAB(
    const vector<uint> &             ubuff,
    vector<double>&                 lvec,
    vector<double>&                 avec,
    vector<double>&                 bvec)
{
    int sz = int(ubuff.size());

    lvec.resize(sz);
    avec.resize(sz);
    bvec.resize(sz);

    for( int j = 0; j < sz; j++ )
    {
        int sR = (ubuff[j]>> 16) & 0xFF;   //<----
        int sG = (ubuff[j] >>  8) & 0xFF;  //<----
        int sB = (ubuff[j]  ) & 0xFF;      //<----
        //------------------------
        // sRGB to XYZ conversion
        // (D65 illuminant assumption)
        //------------------------
        double R = sR/255.0;
        double G = sG/255.0;
        double B = sB/255.0;

        double r, g, b;

        if(R <= 0.04045)    r = R/12.92;
        else                r = pow((R+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
        if(G <= 0.04045)    g = G/12.92;
        else                g = pow((G+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
        if(B <= 0.04045)    b = B/12.92;
        else                b = pow((B+0.055)/1.055,2.4);

        double X = r*0.4124564 + g*0.3575761 + b*0.1804375;
        double Y = r*0.2126729 + g*0.7151522 + b*0.0721750;
        double Z = r*0.0193339 + g*0.1191920 + b*0.9503041;
        //------------------------
        // XYZ to LAB conversion
        //------------------------
        double epsilon = 0.008856;  //actual CIE standard
        double kappa   = 903.3;     //actual CIE standard

        double Xr = 0.950456;   //reference white
        double Yr = 1.0;        //reference white
        double Zr = 1.088754;   //reference white

        double xr = X/Xr;
        double yr = Y/Yr;
        double zr = Z/Zr;

        double fx, fy, fz;
        if(xr > epsilon)    fx = pow(xr, 1.0/3.0);
        else                fx = (kappa*xr + 16.0)/116.0;
        if(yr > epsilon)    fy = pow(yr, 1.0/3.0);
        else                fy = (kappa*yr + 16.0)/116.0;
        if(zr > epsilon)    fz = pow(zr, 1.0/3.0);
        else                fz = (kappa*zr + 16.0)/116.0;

        lvec[j] = 116.0*fy-16.0;
        avec[j] = 500.0*(fx-fy);
        bvec[j] = 200.0*(fy-fz);
    }




}
```

What's the real meaning and income of these symbols ?  Are they mandatory  for the conversion ?

Comment: 1 - >> means right shift (here used to extract 8 specific bits out of a 32 bits value).   2 - yes, they are even quite crucial.

Comment: If your C++ reference guide doesn't cover `>>`, get a new reference. This stuff is pretty fundamental, and you can't learn C++ intuitively, you'll need a guide. At the very least you should have the [C++ book by the language's designer](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) plus others to help explain more strategic aspects of the language. C++ is extremely unforgiving as a langauge, so unless you read up on how to use it properly it can and will make your life utterly miserable when your program crashes or misbehaves.

Comment: These operators are definitely at the heart of the language; it's really no use to ask about the meaning of code if you don't "speak" the language first; so, get a good C++ book / intro and work through it.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. Indeed, I hadn't the opportunity to lean this part of C++ during my courses. I will learn it more deeply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down:

`ubuff` is a vector of `uint`-s. Each `uint` is composed of 32 bits (Possibly 64, but not important for this explanation), or 4 bytes.

So, a single value, e.g. `ubuff[j]` will look like this in memory:

```
|-- Byte1 --|-- Byte2 --|-- Byte3 --|-- Byte4 --|
```

Now that we've got that out of our way, let's talk about the operator `>>`. This is the **shift-right operator**, what it does is rotate the bits in the memory to the right. For example:

```
ubuff[j] >> 8 // ==> |-- ByteX --|-- Byte1 --|-- Byte2 --|-- Byte3 --|
```

Notice how all the bits move right by 8 positions (which is exactly a single byte). The new bytes on the left are filled using 0 or 1 according to the original most significant bit (left-most bit).

Now let's talk about the `&` operator. It performs a bit-wise AND operation on the bits. For example:

```
(ubuff[j] >> 8) & 0xFF // ==> |-- ByteX --|-- Byte1 --|-- Byte2 --|-- Byte3 --|
                       // AND |-- 0x00  --|-- 0x00  --|-- 0x00  --|-- 0xFF  --|
                       // RES |-- 0x00  --|-- 0x00  --|-- 0x00  --|-- Byte3 --|
```

So, we're actually left with `Byte3` from the original `ubuff[j]`.

Same goes for the other expressions:

```
int sR = (ubuff[j] >> 16) & 0xFF; // ==> Byte2
int sG = (ubuff[j] >>  8) & 0xFF; // ==> Byte3
int sB = (ubuff[j]      ) & 0xFF; // ==> Byte4
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I had not the opportunity to learn this part of C++. I will lean it now more deeply. However, I wonder if one can use simply a 2D vector (vector<vector<uint> ubuff ( nbr_pixels, vector<uint>(3,0)) to store the colors of the image for each pixel and hence avoid the shifting process ? (also , if we consider the last part of your explanations, the Byte1 is not used ? )

Comment: @James_keni, you could use a standard container! This method is used because 1) it is very compact 2) it is very fast 3) once you get used to it, it will seem natural 4) you only need one method for serializing and deserializing the data, so you write it once and use it as much as you need. And you are right about your second assumption. It seems that Byte1 is not used, since we only have R,G,B values;